# How to calculate jerk that brings an object to a certain velocity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

My problem appears so simple, yet I can't find an answer:

I have an object with a certain velocity $v_0$ and acceleration $a_0$. My goal is at a time $T$ the new velocity $v_x$ and zero acceleration.

How can I calculate a function over time, that gives me the current positiv or negativ *constant* jerk (derivative of the acceleration) to achieve this?

Comment: Are you assuming that the jerk is constant? If not, then there's really not enough information to solve this.

Comment: Yes, constant jerk, sorry I forgot that. Is there any other information missing?

Comment: Seems fine now. An obvious route is to note that if $a'(t)$ is constant then $a(t)$ is a linear function of time. But it also has to satisfy $a(0)=a_0$ and $a(T)=0$, and there's only one linear function of time that does that. From there you can integrate $a(t)$ from $t=0$ to $T$ to get the change in $v(t)$. (The other simple way is to note that, if $a'(t)=$const, then $a'(t)=\frac{da}{dt}=\frac{\Delta a}{\Delta t}$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jerk (call it $j$) is the third derivative of position.  Your usual equation $x(t)=x_0+v_0t+\frac 12a_0t^2$ adds a term $\frac 1{3!}j_0t^3$.  You can take derivatives to give $v(t)$ and $a(t)$ then use your known points to assess the parameters.  You have one too many constraints.  You can compute the jerk from the difference in accelerations divided by the time, but there is no guarantee that you can meet the velocity change you want.